# JQuery Dialog() can't open again after close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code is a pretty simple and complete JQuery Dialog. Everything works.

Problem is as mentioned at the title in js1.js: (see its comment)

It always try to load the page by calling `horsedlgcontainer.load('page2.html');` never hits the  `else horsedlg.dialog('open');` statement.

Any idea please? Thank you very much!

page1.html ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="horse-link">
    [<a id="horse-link-show-dialog">Click Me</a>]
</div>
<div id="horse-link-dialog-container"></div>
</body>
```

page2.html ...

```
<script src="js2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="horse-dialog" title="Horse!">
Q: When is a horse not a horse?<br />
A: It depends, when a white horse is not a horse.<br /> 
</div>
```

js1.js ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var horselnk = $('#horse-link'),
        horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog'),
        horsedlgcontainer = $('#horse-link-dialog-container'),
        showdlgbtn = $('#horse-link-show-dialog');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    showdlgbtn.click(showHorseDialog);
    function showHorseDialog() {
        if (horsedlg.length==0) 
            horsedlgcontainer.load('page2.html');
        else  //to improve performance, open it again, don't load the same page
            horsedlg.dialog('open'); //Why never come here?!?       
    }
});
```

js2.js ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog'),
        horselnk = $('#horse-link');
    horsedlg.dialog({
        modal: true, autoOpen: true, resizable: false, 
        height: 500, width: 350, closeOnEscape: true,
        show: {effect:'puff',percent:150,duration:250},
        hide: {effect:'puff',percent:110,duration:250}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only evaluating `horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog')` once, and it's before the content is loaded, so its `.length` property is always zero.

---

I suspect you'll also run into problems with loading a secondary JS file when you load the dialog content.  A single JS file would be cleaner:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {
        modal: true, autoOpen: true, resizable: false, 
        height: 500, width: 350, closeOnEscape: true,
        show: {effect:'puff',percent:150,duration:250},
        hide: {effect:'puff',percent:110,duration:250}                    
    };

    var loaded = $.Deferred();
    $('#horse-link-show-dialog').on('click', function() {
        var state = loaded.state();
        if (state === 'resolved') {
            $('#horse-dialog').dialog('open');
        } else if (state === 'pending') {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            $('#horse-link-dialog-container').load('page2.html')
               .fail(loaded.reject);
               .done(function() {
                    $('#horse-dialog').dialog(options);
                    loaded.resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This uses a jQuery deferred object to indicate whether the dialog box has finished loading or not.

NB: code untested - jsfiddle isn't good for testing AJAX.

Comment: Cool. "only evaluating horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog') once, and it's before the content is loaded" That hits the nail on the head! Thanks for the Deferred() function. I had something like this before... Do you think it is good enough? Var loading = $('#loading-overlay');
    horsedlgcontainer.hide(); 
    loading.show();
    horsendlgcontainer.load('js2.js',
                            function () {
                                 loading.hide();
                                 horsedlgcontainer.show();
                             });

Answer (score 3):

As metnioned by @Alnitak the issue is you are trying to search for #horse-dialog even before the element is available in the dom..in your case it will be available after the page2.html load.

Tweak your code to as below and you can do away with js2.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var horsedlgOptions = {
        modal: true, autoOpen: true, resizable: false, 
        height: 500, width: 350, closeOnEscape: true,
        show: {effect:'puff',percent:150,duration:250},
        hide: {effect:'puff',percent:110,duration:250}
    };
    var horselnk = $('#horse-link'),
        horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog'),
        horsedlgcontainer = $('#horse-link-dialog-container'),
        showdlgbtn = $('#horse-link-show-dialog');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    showdlgbtn.click(showHorseDialog);
    function showHorseDialog() {
        if (horsedlg.length==0) 
            horsedlgcontainer.load('page2.html');
                        horsedlg = horsedlgcontainer.find("#horse-dialog");
                        horsedlg.dialog(horsedlgOptions);
        else  //to improve performance, open it again, don't load the same page
            horsedlg.dialog('open'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: nice, but you need to not open the dialog until the page2 content has finished loading...

Comment: Good catch. Updated the options to autoOpen:false

Comment: Didn't I reference to horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog') in the head of each of the $(document).ready functions already? Or should I pull it outside $(document).ready function? Looks like I am confused about the scopes.

Comment: @Cybernate I don't think you nailed it yet - you catch the dialog not being loaded, but the user might have to press the button twice.

Comment: The code you had earlier was fine if the horse-dialog div was already present on the page. However you were loading the element via ajax, hence you execute $("#horse-dialog") jquery is unable to find any element hence on that page since the horse dialog is later added to the page via horsedlgcontainer.load.

Comment: @Alnitak: Man I think I need my coffee :) ...I think the autoOpen:true was correct the way it was.

Comment: `autoOpen` is correct, but there's nothing to prevent the user from clicking the button again (causing a new load) in between the `.load()` and `.dialog()` calls.

Comment: @Alnitak, I actually have more code making dialog container display:none and a loading overlay between .load() and .dialog(), I cut those out for easier reading. So, thanks, I got that covered already.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `horsedlg` is locally defined within the first `$(document).ready` function - so when that code is executed `horsedlg.length` equals `0` as the DOM element with the `id` of `horse-dialog` isnt present on the page.

You cannot change that locally defined variable - so the `length` always equals 0.

You could do this instead :

```
function showHorseDialog() {
    var horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog');
    if (horsedlg.length == 0) {
        horsedlgcontainer.load('page2.html');
    } else { //to improve performance, open it again, don't load the same page
        horsedlg.dialog('open'); //Why never come here?!?  
    }     
}
```

Comment: Didn't I reference to horsedlg = $('#horse-dialog') in the head of each of the $(document).ready functions already? Or should I pull it outside $(document).ready function? Looks like I am confused about the scopes.

Comment: @Tom both variables are both local - [see this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/4wtmj/) (check the console)